# Getting value from an input field Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, input-field

I have a form which fills the input fields on page load off of MySQL server, but when I try to assign it's value to a JavaScript variable, it crashes.

Here is JS;

```
 function getTotal(e)
  {
    total = myform2.1.value;

  }
```

It just crashes and here is my html/php;

```
    <?php
include('connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM zones WHERE id= 1");
$result->bindParam('1', $id);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<form action="edit.php" method="POST" class="elegant-aero" name="myform2">
<input type="hidden" name="memids" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="1" value="<?php echo $row['1']; ?>" /><br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="2" value="<?php echo $row['2']; ?>" /><br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="3" value="<?php echo $row['3']; ?>" /><br>
<input type="button" value="za" id="secret" onclick="getTotal(this)"/>
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Basically I fill the HTML input fields with data from MySQL but the JavaScript variable `total` didn't couldn't retrieve the value, although the HTML input field gets the value just fine from the MySQL server via PHP, any thoughts??

Comment: You could give some id to input field and get value by using javascript.

Comment: You can try with `document.getElementById("1").value`, if you want to give your field id as numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `myform2.1.value;`. Javascript doesn't understand why you're having number (1) after a dot (myform2.).

Best solution would be to rename the fields so that their names don't begin with a number but rather with a letter (such as name="input1" etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would just give it a unique id value such as id='text1' and get the value by:

```
document.getElementById('text1').value
```